Flutter can't extend dart class with executeLib
I want to be able execute dart code from a string, but I can't seem to be able to extend a class within the code in the string.
Here is a basic example. With this code I get this error: Rejecting promise with error: Unexpected null value.
But if I remove the extends Animal from the Dog class, It works fine and I don't get this error. Any ideas?
import 'package:dart_eval/dart_eval.dart';
import 'package:dart_eval/dart_eval_bridge.dart';
import 'package:dart_eval/dart_eval_extensions.dart';
import 'package:dart_eval/stdlib/core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Animal {
}

void main(List<String> args) {
  final source = '''
    class Dog extends Animal  {

    }
    Dog test() {
       final dog = Dog();
       return dog;
    }
    int sum(int a, int b) {
      return a + b;
    }

    int calculate() {
      test();
      return sum(1, 1);
    }
  ''';

  final compiler = Compiler();
  compiler.defineBridgeClasses([]);

  final program = compiler.compile({'example': {'main.dart': source}});

  final runtime = Runtime.ofProgram(program);

  final result = runtime.executeLib('package:example/main.dart', 'test', []);

  print(result);
}



Guess there is an extent to which runtime, string-evaluated codes can work with the Dart VM.
Have you tried declaring Animal (or any other super class) inside the string and it worked? Maybe try let's see. If it does, then the issue is that, in the second runtime, the Animal class is absent. Or if present, it is not named "Animal".
Dart has an aggressive compiler and garbage collector. Chances are that when the code is run, the compiler assigns low-level memory references to classes. And then at runtime, those classes are something else (I stand to be corrected here).
Secondly, to evaluate string codes, we need a compiler and runtime as you specified. These ones are technically separate from those that got loaded when your program first ran. They are sandboxed. They don't know the oontents of the previous (or parent runtime).
Even if you share the runtimes, well, compile-times where different and the compiler would have allocated different references and hence still won't work.

String-ran codes are a nice-feature but we have to admit its limits.
I don't know what your use case is, but I'm pretty sure that you will rethink a better solution.
Cheers!

I tried adding the Animal class in the string, I am getting a different error:
Rejecting promise with error: CompileError: Could not find declaration "Animal." at unknown (file package:example/main.dart)
I am on web and I want to be able to have code that I can change dynamically. Well I would even be okay if I need to refresh the page after changing the code. It seems to be difficult on web since I can't save and load source. I even tried having a .dart file that I can change and then reload but can't seem to figure it out for web.

Why not use JavaScript directly? Dart can't do everything. It is worth accepting its limitations. Dart will have to first transpile to JS and the compiler is not in the browser to do those updates.
